# How to change the color of points with special conditions in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that includes students' id and grades in different subjects, and I want the lessons that have passed (> 10) to be shown in green and lessons that have been failed to be shown in red.

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"Math":[2,20,12,12,5,10,9.75,17],
                 "Physics":[3,16,13,18,6,10,9,10],
                 "Chemistry":[10,19,5,17,16.5,14.75,10,4]},
                 index=[331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def colors(val):
    color = 'red' if val <= 10 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
df.style.applymap(colors)
```

Comment: What does applymap() do?